# Unit Tests Stopped Working and Stuck in Pending State VS2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a somewhat major issue here and I have no idea how to debug the problem. First off I am running VS2012 Update 2 (v11.0.60315.01). Unit Tests *had* been running and I noticed today that they quit working. I was working on something different past week or so so it's been at least a week or 2 since I last ran any unit tests.

All of the tests are stuck in the `Pending` state in the `Unit Test Session` window. I even tried spinning up a new test harness and running some simple unit tests. They behave identically, so I don't think this is a single solution issue.

I have obviously rebooted the machine which included restarting VS.NET 2012 as well. I'm not getting any errors, messages, problems, etc. The unit tests are all just stuck in the `Pending` state and none of them will run.

I ran the .dll that comprises my tests using the **vstest.console.exe** tool and I get the result "**Test Run Successful**", "**Test execution time: 0.4952 seconds**". OK, this tells me I have a problem with VS2012 because the tests run independently using the command line.

How can I debug this issue? I see solutions for deleting settings files for individual solutions but this seems like an issue across the board with VS2012. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have Resharper 7.1.1 or 7.1.2 installed? There is a private update (7.1.3) that resolves an issue with the test runner and VS 2012.2

Comment: Yes I do!! Let me get this.

Comment: @jessehouwing - That was the answer! Actually reform your comment as an answer along with link for download and any other information and I'll mark it. That was *exactly* the issue.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're using Resharper, then there is an issue with version 7.1.2 and below in combination with Visual Studio 2012 Update 2.

Jetbrains has [released a new version (7.1.3) which solved the issue](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/resharper-713-is-available-for-visual-studio-2012-update-2/), the latest EAP also resolved this issue.

If you're running an older version of Visual Studio 2012 and are experiencing these issues with Resharper 8, then make sure you install Visual Studio Update 2 at the least. If I had to choose, I'd always install the latest version, which would be [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520)

Comment: +1 Thanks I was about to restore my system due to this problem, glad I found this!

Comment: I have same problem, as author described, with resharper 8. Should I degrade my R# to 7.1.3?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem with ReSharper 8.0.14.856

Comment: What if problem remains even in 8.1 version?

Comment: For those that are using 8.1, are you running it as a floating window? When i have the test runner as a separate floating window, it gets stuck in pending. When i re-attach it to the main window, it doesn't seem to be an issue anymore. Really strange.

Answer (score 2):

The 7.1.3 version of Resharper also works following **Update 3** for Visual Studio 2012. Not sure about the newest version 8 but that older version is still available for download [here](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-).

Comment: The link above doesn't reference the right location anymore. This will help: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-

Comment: Thanks for updating this @SouthShoreAK . Luckily my old link redirects to the same "Where can I download an old/previous ReSharper version?" page now too.